# Use graph.facebook.com to get URL's and Names of Photos

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to get the URL's and names of the Photos contained in a Facebook Photo Album.
I know this is possible through graph.facebook.com but I don't know where to find the ID of an Album.

As an example you can use this Album: http://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.210725979538.130908.69116329538

Which one of the Numbers is the Album ID? And How do I get the Photo URL's with name??

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just get the [/albums](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=thebeatles/albums) relationship. For your example:
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=thebeatles%2Falbums

Then use [10150213069439539/photos](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=10150213069439539/photos) to get the photos of the first album (or any other album you want, just change the id based on what you got from /albums).

I suggest you to [read the whole Graph API Core Concepts page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) and trying its examples.

And also read the [album](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/) and [photo](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/) documentation.